# How can I get the appsetting.json value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some trouble of getting the configuration of appsetting,my appsetting.json looks like this:

```
  "HttpSetting": {
"Url": "http://47.114.40.168:8080/Park-PServer/PServer/do_paccess",
"From": "Park-PServer",
"MsgCodeBody": [
  {
    "MsgCode": "MSG_O_AUTH_LOGIN",
    "ReqBody": {
      "UserType": "1",
      "OptCode": "liuyu001",
      "Pwd": "a1"
    }
  },
  {
    "MsgCode": "MSG_O_PKMNG_GETPARKLIST",
    "ReqBody": {
      "PageFlg": 1,
      "PageNo": 1,
      "PageRowNo": 10
    }
  }
]
```

}

and my HttpSetting extends IOptions looks like this:

```
public class AnKuaiHttpSetting : IOptions<AnKuaiHttpSetting>
{
    public AnKuaiHttpSetting Value => this;

    /// <summary>
    /// Url
    /// </summary>
    public string Url { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// body-header
    /// </summary>
    public string From { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MsgCodeBody> MsgCodeBody { get; set; }
}
```

The MsgCodeBody.cs is:

```
public class MsgCodeBody 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string MsgCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public object ReqBody { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I get the **dynamic** ReqBody from appsetting.json,obviously using object doesn't work,can anybody help me? best appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it as a JObject should work

```
 public JObject ReqBody
```

You can then access those properties with

```
 var pageFlg = ReqBody.GetValue("PageFlg").ToString();
```

or

```
 if(ReqBody.TryGetValue("PageFlg", out pageFlagJToken))
      //process page flag
```

you can also iterate through properties using

```
 foreach(var reqBodyProp in ReqBody.Properties())
      //do stuff
```

Comment: I try to define it using JObject,but still failed, the MsgCodeBody.ReqBody is {{}} empty 
 when I debugg,is there something I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using IDictionary<string, object> can resolve this issue,it's just like this:

```
public class MsgCodeBody 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string MsgCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public IDictionary<string,object> ReqBody { get; set; }
}
```

And when you want to use one of the ReqBody, you can first define the matching class and deserialize it,just like this:

```
var reqBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthLoginReqBody>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject( MsgCodeBody.ReqBody));
```